# Resize font of label in custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, resize, uilabel

So I have a custom table view cell and I want a label to be resized based on the text in it. I've already tried doing this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method-

```
        cell.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        [cell.titleLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:8.0/[UIFont labelFontSize]];
```

I also tried setting minimum scale factor and minimum font size in IB...but the label font doesn't resize.

The case I want to take care of is the case where the text in the label is larger than the phone width and so I want to resize when that happens.

What's going wrong/How do I achieve that?

Comment: If you had implement custom cell, also implement viewWillLayoutSubview method and change the size of label depending on the text there.

Comment: so viewWillLayoutSubview is not called...

Comment: @C_X `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is a method of `UIViewController`, not `UIView` or `UITableViewCell`. Perhaps you mean `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: rmaddy - do you have any idea why the label is not resizing?

Comment: viewWillLayoutSubview method will call every time when a view will layout its subviews. You should add this method in customCell class.

Comment: yes I added that - that's not a method of the UIView class

Comment: @rmaddy yes sorry equalnt method to views is layoutSubviews... you right...

Comment: right, so I added the adjustFontSizeToFitWidth method to the layoutSubviews and it still didn't work

Comment: [cell.titleLabel sizeTofit]; It will make label fit to size...

Comment: won't that expand the label? I don't want that...I want the label to be the same and the text font size to change

Comment: Possible duplicate: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2844397/2298998)