# UILabel: adjust font size to height with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

I'd like to have several labels one below the other. The are sized with AutoLayout, I'd like to have the font size as big as possible. `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` only works for the width, but the I get the following result

[image]

Comment: I created this [AdjustableLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33657604/1121497), that can adjust text size to the whole frame, not just the width.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-calculate your content height by calling (it may be a little easier to manage by having your layout built as a tableview, if it isn't already):

```
[cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingExpandedSize].height;
```

I've also had to hard code this for a specific purpose (added as a UIFont category):

```
+ (int)contentSizeHeightForItem {
    NSString *cat = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] preferredContentSizeCategory];
    if([cat isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraSmall]) {
        return 84;
    } else if([cat isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategorySmall]) {
        return 86;
    } else if([cat isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryMedium]) {
        return 88;
    } else if([cat isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryLarge]) {
        return 92;
    } else if([cat isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraLarge]) {
        return 94;
    } else if([cat isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraLarge]) {
        return 98;
    } else if([cat isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraExtraLarge]) {
        return 102;
    }
    return 80;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your font is constant, you can calculate the necessary height of the labels from the font like so:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
[label setFont:font];
[view addSubview:label];

double labelHeight = font.pointSize + fabs(font.descender);
[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[label(labelHeight)]"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:@{@"labelHeight" : @(labelHeight)}
                                                               views:@{@"label" : label}]];
```

This will guarantee that the full height of the font will be taken into account when setting constraints.