# Adjust Font Size to Fit Bounding Rect?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel which has a defined frame:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: someFrame)
```

**Is it possible that the font size will be adjusted to fit the height of the bounding Rect or fit the height and width of the bounding rect?**

Comment: there is a property called `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, you could try.

Comment: Is there also one that adjusts with height?

Comment: Seems not. It is more complicated than you think to let font size fit rect I guess. What's your true problem?

Comment: The true problem is what I wrote.

Comment: I don't think you could fit the height and width without stretching or squashing the font. If you want to fit the height, I think you would have to loop through different font sizes until you get the one with the height that matches you label. This post proposes a solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270091/uilabel-adjust-font-size-to-height-with-autolayout/30656023#30656023

Answer (score 0):

Set the label's font size to something absurdly large, then set the label's autoshrink to an absurdly small minimum font size. Now your label's font will always fit it's frame.