# UILabel text to fill in the frame width

Tags: swift, uilabel, sizetofit

I want to build typography poster using UILabel

- left and margin: 25
- 320(device width) - 50(sum of the margins) = 270(label width frame)

The font size of each label should change in order to fit in 270 frame width

I try with **sizeToFit()**,**adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=true**

```
var margin = 0;
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(25 , 72, 270, 70));
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left;
label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor();
label.numberOfLines = 1;
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(50.0);
label.text = "Some Text";
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
self.view.addSubview(label);
margin += 60;

let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(25 , CGFloat(72+margin), 270, 70));
label2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left;
label2.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
label2.numberOfLines = 1;
label2.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(45.0);
label2.text = "Some Text Longer";
self.view.addSubview(label2);
```

Screenshot when lable1 and label2 **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=true**

[image]

The text should start from the end of first grey border and end in the beginning at the start of the second grey border

Comment: The size of the font will change according to frame when `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=true`. Isn't it working for you? You have not set it for `label2`

Comment: No adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth don't work. The text have a left padding and dont star the at 25 px. Also println(label.font); font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 50.00pt

Comment: does the text in `label` get clipped?  what is the problem with fontsize being 50 if it fits? You have set it as 50 for `label`

Comment: img - http://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Z35.png I want the text to start from first gray and end the second grey border

Comment: @EvenJohnson can't you make the font larger for that?

Answer (score 6):

`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` does not increase the size of the font in the label to fit the width.

According to Apple's documentation,

> adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is a Boolean value indicating whether the
>   font size should be reduced in order to fit the title string into the
>   label’s bounding rectangle.
>
> Normally, the label text is drawn with the font you specify in the
>   font property. If this property is set to YES, however, and the text
>   in the text property exceeds the label’s bounding rectangle, the
>   receiver starts reducing the font size until the string fits or the
>   minimum font size is reached. In iOS 6 and earlier, this property is
>   effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1.

**You can try increasing the size of the font to fit the width of the frame.**

Source : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit

**You can also use the following method to iteratively find the maximum size that fits the label.**

[How to adjust font size of label to fit the rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844397/how-to-adjust-font-size-of-label-to-fit-the-rectangle)

Comment: label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30.0);
label.text = "Some Text"
label.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(270, 40));
label.sizeToFit();
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;

img - http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/01/16/Screen_Shot_2015-01-16_at_30835_PM.png

Comment: I did not understand your comment. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 4):

This should just work without changing many defaults. The posted code doesn't set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, look like this:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```