# Why UILabel with Lines = 1 and Autoshrink = minimumFontSize(1) is not fitting the text inside its frame?

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, uilabel, uistoryboard

I am really going crazy with this so I hope any of you can point me to the right direction.

I have an app and I designed it with autolayout, so the views and labels resize according to the screen size. The problem comes when resizing the labels. My main goal is to scale the text to fit the label's frame height and width.

The concrete problems is: I placed a one line label in storyboard and I gave it the size font, so it looks great when running the app in the biggest screen possible (iPad pro, so I set the font size to 50). The result is as follows (using xCode preview, I set the label's view background to blue so you can appreciate the frame):
[image]

Then, I configured the autoshrink = minimumFontSize with a minimum font size of 1:
[image]

So the goal is that the text size shrinks to fit the label's frame (height and width) when being used in smaller screens. When previewing it for iPhone 3.5 inch, the result is as follows:
[image]

Why isn`t it shrinking?

And:
Is this the good approach or are there any other tools to fit the text into the frame?
Is this a good procedure to design for different screen sizes?
(I can not believe that I need to programmatically calculate the font size to fit each label like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844397/how-to-adjust-font-size-of-label-to-fit-the-rectangle), that is really a performance killer, there must be another easier way...)

Thanks a lot!

EDIT 1:
Also tried Minimum Font Scale with the same result.

Comment: Have you tried Minimum Font Scale .. ?

Comment: Yes, and the same result..

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Nope... I asked this 2 years ago, and I do not even remember how I solved it in the end, sorry