# Space in Front of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, xcode-storyboard

So I'm mid-way into my first iOS app and I've hit a roadblock.  Every time I try to use a UILabel with a custom font, there seems to be a space in front of the text, which cuts off the end of the text.

Storyboard of the UILabel:

[image: Storyboard of the UILabel]

Characters in the Font:

[image: Characters in the Font]

As you can see, the lowercase a at the end is cut off. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try giving the inset to your label in the storyboard. Or call sizeToFit by code,

Comment: sizeToFit could be a good try, also you can search how to adjust font to fit uilable or how to adjust uilable to fit font. tons of posts here in stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't know how to inset it, but sizeToFit hasn't worked.

Comment: @user2455722 check [this brutal way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844397/how-to-adjust-font-size-of-label-to-fit-the-rectangle) to find the right font size, I use it a lot.

Comment: Ill try it, but it seems really performance intensive

Comment: It didn't work. :(

Comment: I checked this on Pages, and the shift is there too. I think this is a font problem, any suggestions?